# Trigger client-side reload in next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js

## Scenario

The index page uses "getInitialProps" to load data. Then we create a dialog which can create a new data. After creating a new data, the current page should be reloaded.

## Problem

We use `Router.replace('/')` to reload the page. But it triggers a server-side rendering.

## Question

What we need is a client-side reload. The "getInitialProps" function should be called in the browser. So, how to do the client-side reload?

Comment: You can use this handy module https://github.com/shdnx/next-express

Comment: We are using pure next.js now. Have not introduced express yet.

Comment: `getInitialProps` can only be called on server side render, you can always call `componentDidMount` on the client

Comment: Nope. "getInitialProps" can be called in the client-side.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

as of of NextJs 13 Being released the new router Object has the `refresh()` method, which allows you to refresh ( re-fetch ) the data client-side only without having to do a full page reload.

it can be used like the following :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Component(){
  const router = useRouter();

  //this will reload the page without doing SSR
  router.refresh();
}
```

Please keep in mind that this is feature of NextJs 13 Which is currently in beta.

check the beta docs [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/use-router)

credits to fireship for showing the feature 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__mSgDEOyv8

Comment: Next 13 router is no longer under "next/router" module, but "next/navigation" module instead. I suggest you to slightly change your code to avoid missconceptions and errors. More info: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook

Comment: can't seem to get refresh to work with prisma - because it does not follow the fetch pattern.

Comment: This feels like a `router.reload()` from next/router, i,e, like an initial request - really re-create the page on the server and load the response by the browser - very slow. With `router.replace(router.asPath)` it seems, that it just re-fetches the page properties and replaces changed dom branches as needed - much faster.

Answer (score 30):

Assume, a user is on the

`http://www.example.com/profile`

the user has edited the profile and for some reason, you need to reload the same page.

If your case is similar to this, you could use `Router.reload();`

**Remember**, you must import Router object like this `import Router from "next/router";`

For more information: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreload

Answer (score 23):

A better option is to use `router.replace(router.asPath)`

replace does not create a new history item so Back button works as expected

Details explained in this article
https://www.joshwcomeau.com/nextjs/refreshing-server-side-props/

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Component(){
  const router = useRouter();

  router.replace(router.asPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I think `router.asPath` should be the default argument of `router.replace()`.

Comment: just me or aspath doesn't exists ?

Comment: @David it does exist on router object https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: @David try `asPath` with a capital — perhaps it was a typo?

Answer (score 14):

Didn't see an answer that was really what I was looking for,

this worked for me:

```
import Router from 'next/router'

Router.reload(window.location.pathname);
```

Comment: Router.reload() is equal to window.location.reload(), you shouldn't pass an address to it.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `window.location.reload()` if you want to refresh on a client side in nextjs version 13.

Comment: Using Next.js 14 this is the only way I was able to perform a full page reload.

Comment: It's so stupid, what's Next.js team doing? Offering a router hook that cannot do the plain reloading? Not mentioning how much it's changed from pages dir to app dir, crazy breaking changes, yet with poor confusing functionalities...

Answer (score 2):

Running the following code

**pages/index.js**

```
import Router from 'next/router';

function Index({ isServer }) {
  console.log('render', new Date());

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home page. Is it on server? - {isServer ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</h1>

      <button type="button" onClick={() => Router.push('/')}>
        Reload me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  return { isServer: !!req };
};

export default Index;
```

I can see that it `console.log`s render only once on the server even after clicking "Reload me". I can see that `isServer` equals to false after "reload" as well.

How do you exactly reload the page so you see it is rendered on server side?

PS

Here are screenshots:

- [initial load](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7comkxx571xlpe/Screenshot%202018-12-13%2013.51.54.png?dl=0)
- [after clicking reload](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0i7wdf0aosl0uvf/Screenshot%202018-12-13%2013.52.44.png?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I find that `Router.replace('/')` works fine(it is client-side rendering) in my local env. However, it triggers server-side rendering in my production env. I can see the network access in the browser's debug window. The only difference between local and production env is that there is nginx and asset prefix in the production env. It is very odd.

Comment: So, the correct question should be, how does Router.push(or H5 history api) trigger server-side rendering? Let me know if you need the reproduce.

Comment: That is weird. I pushed this example to zeit and it is working fine https://nextjs-test-cldxfttoi.now.sh/ Do you use a custom server.js file?

Comment: No, I don't customize server.js.

Comment: Here is the repro: "https://locationbackbone.top/scenariobus/", username: "testbus@bytebilling.com", password: "qwe!@#123". It is a sandbox, so feel free to test it.

Comment: After login, you can click the last icon card (like a portrait), then click "back" button of the browser, you'll see the server-side rendering.

Comment: Another case is that, click the portrait icon, then click the top-left button, it will pop up a dialog, fill all the fields with random characters, then click the blue button (whose label is OK in English). Again, server render.

Comment: In my local laptop, it is client-side rendering. It is too weird to debug. :(

Comment: The third case, after login, just click the top-left "bus" icon, server render. In my local laptop, client render.

Comment: I think clicking "back button" results into server rendering https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3065 and it is expected behaviour

Comment: "back button" results into client rendering in my local laptop.

Comment: After a long-time investigation, I find that the character number of asset prefix must less then 4. So, `assetPrefix: '/bus'`, client rendering; `assetPrefix: '/bus1'`, server rendering. It should be a bug of next.js.

Comment: Confirmed! Set asset prefix will cause this bug. Have opened an issue to next.js.

Comment: I have the same issue! In local is working fine but not in production. Also I have different `assetPrefix`... Do you find any solution @JimJin?

Comment: Don't use assetPrefix. It's the enemy to client-side redirection. Keep every pages in the main project and make the contents of the page the components which could reside in sub-projects.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using AppRouter and need to force refresh, you can use follow code.

```
router.push(window.location.href);
router.refresh();
```

Comment: Is it OK to only use `router.refresh();`?

Comment: only ```router.refresh()``` didn't work in my end.

Comment: Does `router.push(window.location.href);` trigger server load?

Comment: I expect that's just push or you can use replace.

Answer (score 1):

It may help someone, If you are using nextjs Link its actually preloades page if you need default reload you need to use a tag not a Link

Comment: Altough this was already explained to me, i still used a Link for changing the language. switching it to an anchor tag made sure the page was reloaded and translations were changed!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using NextJS 14 with app router. As the earlier solutions suggested

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Component(){
  const router = useRouter();

  //this will reload the page without doing SSR
  router.refresh();
}
```

Couldn't find `asPath`, it doesn't exist.

In my case plain `window.location.reload()` worked for me perfectly fine. It only reloaded the client and not the server.