# Next.js Reload on Link

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is it possible to reload on click on a Link component from next/link? I tried to put my own function on the child div from the link that says to reload on click. But then it reloads before the route has changed and it didn't change route anymore.

```
const router = useRoute();

const hanldeRefresh = () => {
   router.reload();
} 


<Link href={title.slug}>
   <button onClick={handleRefresh} class="button">{title.buttonText}</div>
</Link>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger client-side reload in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739908/trigger-client-side-reload-in-next-js)

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to do so? I'd question if this is the right approach for whatever problem you're having.

Comment: When i go from titles/[slug].js to an other titles/[slug].js, all the components doesn't rerender. So all the images do not so the placeholder="blur" anymore it just is gone for a sec and then the new image appears. Also, I use swiper.js for a carousel slider, the images in the slider do not update and the looping images are the old images from the first titles/[slug].js. Could it be something with getstaticprops? Should i render this client side?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Link, you can use router like this

```js
const router = useRoute();

const handleClick = async (title) => {
  // Wait for route change before do anything
  await router.push(title);
  // Reload after routing
  router.reload();
} 


//<Link href={title.slug}>
   <button onClick={() => handleClick(title.slug)} class="button">
      {title.buttonText}
   </button>
//</Link>
```